# JavaScript get number from string that contain '0' in front of number

Tags: javascript

If I have the string `"PK000019"` how can I remove the PK and leading 0s to get just `"19"`?

Comment: Do you actually have a question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this something like what you're looking for?

```
var code = "PK000019";
var code_num = parseInt(code.substr(2), 10); //returns 19
```

You can get the full product code back from the number like so:

```
var code_num = 19;
var code = "PK" + ("00000" + code_num).slice(-6); //returns PK000019
```

Comment: @Wallflower This should work for any code as long as it fits into the format `PKXXXXXX`.

Answer (score 3):

If you need something that targets the prefix PK specifically, you can use regular expression for validation.

```
var code = "PK033311";
var code_num = parseInt(/PK([0-9]+)/.exec(code)[1],10);
```

Reconstitution of the code as mentioned by Hydrothermal is the same.

If you have a specific number of digits (6);

```
var code = "PK033311";
var code_num = parseInt(/PK([0-9]{6})/.exec(code)[1],10);
```